# One for the older, nostalgic crowd

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My big brother was bright, smooth and fat
>
> I'm just as bright, but slim and matte
>
> The how changed, why stayed the same
>
> To paint a picture time and time again

What am I?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you're a

> flatscreen display

My big brother was bright, smooth and fat

> old cathode ray tube based screens were bulky

I'm just as bright, but slim and matte

> flatscreens provide as much light as older screens, but are slimmer

The how changed, why stayed the same

> The method of picture generation is completely different, but the purpose is the same

To paint a picture time and time again

> Screens create multiple successive frames to give the impression of a moving picture

Comment: Not surprised that didn't take long but well done none the less.  +1

Comment: I think you missed the smooth, and fat reference. I believe that refers to CRTs having a smooth glass screen, and LCDs having matte screens.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson I think you're right, with an addendum: CRT screens bulged outwards; i.e. they were fat.

Comment: They also bulged inwards.

Comment: (So, I guess other aspiring solvers should avoid the comments sections)

Answer (score 9):

I know the correct answer is already in but I had a slightly different version :

I think you're a

> Camera flash

My big brother was bright, smooth and fat

> The old bulbous single use glass bulbs

I'm just as bright, but slim and matte

> Current LED white flash has a flat matte yellow phosphor

The how changed, why stayed the same

> Original flash bulbs burned magnesium, LEDs are semiconductor based

To paint a picture time and time again

> Many photographs require the additional light of a camera flash

Comment: This answer required obscure enough knowledge that I'm not going to kick myself too hard for this puzzle having more than one possible answer.  And - not being able to mark both correct - I'll just have to give you a big, well earned, well polished, shiny +1 (even though you made me learn about bulb history...)

Comment: @Brent Hackers - you did say nostalgic - the popping of flash bulbs has got to be in there for a few...

Comment: Oh, I'm much too young to know anything about that...  Much, much too young...